# Remove spaces between words

Tags: spacing

Can someone help me with this thing? when I type in TexMaker this command:

```
\hspace{15pt}Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.
```

in pdf is written like this: [image]

How can I remove those spaces?

Comment: Could you provide a complete minimal example, of your document class and the (relevant) packages? Otherwise we probably cannot help you, since this seems to be related to your classes justification setting.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a normal `article` document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you use and which commands come immediately before and immediately after the code snippet you've posted so far.

Comment: you have `\parfillskip` set to 0pt (which is far from being the default setting) (why the `\hspace` ?)

Answer (score 7):

You  must have something equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}

\hspace{15pt}Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; 
and I'm not sure about the universe.
\end{document}
```

which makes

[image]

If you remove the `\hspace` and remove the setting of `\parfillskip` which is specifying that the last line of the pargarph must reach the right margin, then you get

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity;
and I'm not sure about the universe.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity;
and I'm not sure about the universe.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you're saying that OP needed to remove the `\hspace` command?  Could you add some non-tex commentary about what you've done and why?

Comment: Can you describe the difference between your answer and the already existing answer?